# Dynamic Grunt Watch configuration

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-less

My site file structure is something like this:

```
app
    less
        themes
            default
            modern
            etc
public
    themes
        default
            css
        modern
            css
        etc
```

So `/app/less/themes/{{ themeName }}/*.less` will compile into `/public/themes/{{ themeName }}/css/*.css`.

I have my Grunt Less task set up dynamically and working fine.
Example: `grunt less:compileTheme:modern`

```
less: {
  compileTheme: {
    options: {
      compress: false,
      yuicompress: false,
      optimization: 2,
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapFilename: "public/themes/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/css/styles.css.map",
      sourceMapURL: "/themes/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/css/styles.css.map"
    },
    files: {
      "public/themes/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/css/styles.css": "app/less/themes/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/styles.less"
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get the Grunt Watch task working. Ideally, it'll see the theme folder name and run the grunt task as `grunt less:compileTheme:{{ themeName }}`:

```
watch: {
    themeCss: {
        files: "app/less/themes/{{ themeName }}/**/*.less",
        tasks: ["less:compileTheme:{{ themeName }}"],
        options: {
          spawn: false
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? And/or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your watch task to run the `less:compileTheme`-task without themeName, and watch all less files in your themes folder:

```
watch: {
    themeCss: {
        files: "app/less/themes/**/*.less",
        tasks: ["less:compileTheme"],
        options: {
          spawn: false
        }
    }
}
```

now you can add a watch event-handler where you get the changed file. extract the themeName, and configure your less-task:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  var themeName = filepath.split('/')[3];
  grunt.config('less.compileTheme.files', {
    "public/themes/" + themeName + "/css/styles.css": "app/less/themes/" + themeName + "/styles.less"
  });
});
```

of course the detection of your themeName should be more reliable, but i think you get the idea on how to do dynamic watching!

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error: "Unexpected token '+'" at the first " + themeName + "
I tried making the object a string but that didn't work either.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb. It's standard JS and you can't have an object property as a variable like that. So I just have to use obj[prop] = val; notation and it's all good. Thanks!